# spl_autoload_register in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, twilio

I'm currently trying to use the Twilio PHP library that uses spl_autoload_register to include its classes.

```
function Services_Twilio_autoload($className) {
    if (substr($className, 0, 15) != 'Services_Twilio') {
        return false;
    }
    $file = str_replace('_', '/', $className);
    $file = str_replace('Services/', '', $file);
    return include dirname(__FILE__) . "/Twilio.php";
}

spl_autoload_register('Services_Twilio_autoload');
```

I throw in this code:

```
require_once('Library/Services/Twilio.php');

$client = new Services_Twilio($this->sid, $this->token);
```

And then I get this error when running it:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Services_Twilio_autoload() (previously declared in ...\Twilio\Library\Services\Twilio.php:9) in ... \Twilio\Library\Services\Twilio.php on line 16
```

This code runs off Zend, and already has a bootstrap with _initAutoload(). I'm not sure where or how I should implement the autoload for this library as I'm not very familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have reproduced the problem.

To correct it, I just add `require_once('Services/Twilio.php');` in the bootstrap like this:

```
require_once('Services/Twilio.php');

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{    
  ....
```

In my case, I put `Services` directory in `library` directory (where is Zend directory).

And in a controller, I can call `Services_Twilio` like you :

```
$client = new Services_Twilio($this->sid, $this->token);
```

I hope it will help you. :)

Comment: This actually works. However I decided to run the library using composer instead, which also works.